# ExtJS custom state not committing to server

Tags: extjs, state

I have extended the Ext.tree.Panel and added a new state property called "selectedNodes" which is supposed to save the state of the checked tree nodes, updating the state anytime a node is clicked.  The problem is the state is not being committed to the server whenever the node is clicked.  The first time I click a node it seems to trigger, and other state triggers such as collapsing the panel fire correctly and even commit the nodes that are selected.  The client-side statesave event fires, however if I watch the dev tools network traffic no call is being made to the server to commit the changes.  Here is the relevant code:

```
Ext.define('Common.CheckboxTreePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.checkboxtreepanel',
    stateful: true,
    stateId: 'tree',
    initComponent: function()
    {
        this.addEvents('selectednodeschange');
        this.addStateEvents('selectednodeschange');
    },
    getState: function()
    {
        var state = this.callParent(arguments) || {};
        Ext.apply(state, { selectedNodes: this.selected() });
        return state;
    },
    applyState: function(state)
    {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.selected(state.selectedNodes, true);
    }
});
```

Comment: which StateManager do you use that should send requests to a server?
both `LocalStorageProvider` and `CookieProvider` are saving all date on the client sid.

Comment: @Jandalf I'm using the Ext.ux.state.HttpProvider

Comment: Ok then I have no idea, but you could change the provider do a client one to check if its a problem with this HttpProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  I was overriding the encode/decodeValue methods in the state provider, which was receiving the state object via reference and returning the same reference instead of creating a copy of the object.  Cloning the object before returning fixed the problem.